# Most effective way to retrieve, edit, and then store data from many files in bash

Tags: json, bash, file, parsing

So I have a bunch of data in .log files. The columns are tab separated, but I only need data from columns 2 and 7 (Although there is not always guaranteed to be data in column 7, and there are more columns after 7. In this instance there would be a double tab to before column 8)

My current method is EXTREMELY slow and I feel like there must be a better way as I am going through the data more often than I should be.

```
   #First I iterate through all the files and att them to data.raw.log
   cat $f >> data.raw.log
   #Then cut out unneeded data.
   cut -f2,7 data.raw.log > data.log
   #I then need to parse the data into JSON
   while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a entry
   do
     if [ ! -z  ${entry[1]} ]; then
       echo "FORMATTED JSON HERE WITH ${entry[0]} AND ${entry[1]}" >> data.json
     fi
   done < data.log
```

The obvious issue is that I am going through the data twice to cut and then add when I only need to once. This is proving to be EXTREMELY slow, any ideas on speed improvement would be helpful.

Comment: You don't need to concat all the files to a single file. Just perform the cut command to each file. Loop the files like ' files=`ls *.log; for file in $files; do; cut-command; done; '. The semicolon indicates a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk`:

```
awk -F'\t' '$7 != "" { print "FORMATTED JSON HERE WITH " $2 " AND " $7 }' * > data.json
```

Here, I assume that all the files are in the current directory. You should be able to adjust this easily to accommodate the actual location of the files.

Comment: This wrongly assumes that if there are at least 7 columns then it must be printed - not filtering entries where column 7 (even when there are more than 7 columns) is empty.

Comment: Thank you for this! Really helped speed things up!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you cut the data into a file, then parse that file.  That is kind of lengthy.  Not only that, but you first copy all the data from one file to another.

You can achieve the same thing with a single little awk script:

```
 $ cat file*.log | awk -F'\t' '{if ($7 != "") print "Formatted data here with " $1 " and " $7}' >output.log
```

Awk takes the input as tokens, $1 and $7 (tab separated), and checks if $7 is empty or not.  If not, then print the data formatted as you like.

Comment: Why would you use `cut` over fields when you're going into `awk`? Awk is ideally suited for processing fields. Just tell it that tab is a separator.

Comment: Because I don't know awk well enough to know the -F parameter ;)

Comment: Awk can also take multiple files on the command line. `awk 'script' file1.log file2.log file3.log`.

Comment: It looks like the right answer is a combination of both of the two existing ones.  I'll optimize mine to be better

Comment: Can't get it to handle multiple files, so have to pipe from cat still.